# Автоматическая ширина для grid-елементов

Tags: css, css-grid

Всем привет.
Уже который час бьюсь над задачей, суть такая, что у нас есть грид контейнер, нужно что бы элементы шли друг за другом, сейчас же почему то текст идет на всю ширину, и кнопка шире положенного(

```css
.upload {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  pointer-events: none
}
.upload:before {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: "Выбрать " attr(data-document);
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  -moz-appearance: initial;
  appearance: initial;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: auto;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 34px;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px rgba(52,52,52,.2),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  background-color: #ff4252;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.upload:hover::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px rgba(52,52,52,.2),inset 0 5px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.15)
}
.upload__label {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: .4em;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block
}
.upload__control[required] ~ .upload__label::after {
  content: " * ";
  color: #ee3f58
}
.upload__control[hidden] {
  display: none
}
.upload__file {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px
}
.upload__close {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 6px
}
```

```html
  <label class="upload" data-name="Выбрать" data-document=""> 
    <span class="upload__file">Имя файла.pdf</span> 
    <span class="upload__close"></span>
    <input class="upload__control" type="file" name="TODO" hidden=""> 
    <span class="upload__label">Лейбл</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо, чтобы сетка была выстроена по контенту, то есть значение `min-content`. Ну и не забывайте пользоваться `repeat()`,

```css
.upload {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  pointer-events: none
}
.upload:before {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: "Выбрать " attr(data-document);
  appearance: initial;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: auto;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 34px;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px rgba(52,52,52,.2),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  background-color: #ff4252;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.upload:hover::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px rgba(52,52,52,.2),inset 0 5px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.15)
}
.upload__label {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: .4em;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block
}
.upload__control[required] ~ .upload__label::after {
  content: " * ";
  color: #ee3f58
}
.upload__control[hidden] {
  display: none
}
.upload__file {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px
}
.upload__close {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 6px
}
```

```html
<label class="upload" data-name="Выбрать" data-document=""> 
    <span class="upload__file">Имя файла.pdf</span> 
    <span class="upload__close"></span>
    <input class="upload__control" type="file" name="TODO" hidden=""> 
    <span class="upload__label">Лейбл</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое